# In julia, how to dispatch different kinds of "MutableNamedTuple"

Tags: julia, tuples, subtyping

My Julia code uses many different kinds of `MutableNamedTuples` e.g.

```
box = MutableNamedTuple

CSV(file::String)  = box(rows=[], file=file)
NUM() = box(n=0,mu=0, sd=0, m2=0)
```

I want to dispatch methods on the different kinds of `MutableNamedTuples`.

But how do I do that?

Is it possible to generate subtypes of  `MutableNamedTuples`?

Or is there a different approach I should take?

(Ideally, one as succinct as using `MutableNamedTuples` but I'll take anything, with thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

You can dispatch but it seems to be less comfortable than using mutable `structs`.

Consider the following functions:

```
using MutableNamedTuples

f(a::MutableNamedTuple{(:x, :y), Tuple{Base.RefValue{Int64}, Base.RefValue{Int64}}}) = 10*a.x

f(a::MutableNamedTuple{(:x, :z), Tuple{Base.RefValue{Int64}, Base.RefValue{Int64}}}) = 100*a.x
```

And now you could do

```
julia> a1 = MutableNamedTuple(x=1, y=2);

julia> a2 = MutableNamedTuple(x=1, z=2);

julia> f(a1)
10

julia> f(a2)
100
```

If you want to dispatch only on field names you could do:

```
julia> f(a::MutableNamedTuple{(:x, :z), T}) where T = 1000*a.x;

julia> f(MutableNamedTuple(x=1.0, z=2))
1000.0
```

Comment: so i this approach i would have to list all fields of all my MutableNamedTuple in every dispatch (which sounds kinda verbose)? not just the ones that are different ?

Comment: thanks for the pointer to mutable structs. i looked at them again (at https://www.matecdev.com/posts/julia-structs.html ) and as you say, they give me  (with @kwdef) all that i need  . lets close this discussion.

Comment: Have also a look at Parameters.jl and `@with_kw`, IHMO this is a slightly nicer API than `@kwdef`.